# I'm trying to create a gcp cloud bucket using json apis and got following error

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, rest

curl --request POST 
'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{"name":""}' 
--compressed

Error Message:

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "CORS request contains X-Origin header",
"errors": [
{
"message": "CORS request contains X-Origin header",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "corsRequestWithXOrigin"
}
]
}
}

Answer (score 2):

If you use an access token, you can remove your API key. I personally follow [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert) and perform this requets, and it worked

```
curl --request POST 'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]' \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer  [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]" \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"name":"[MY_BUCKET_NAME]"}' --compressed
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I have tried using the mentioned documentation and ran into issues which wasn't mentioned in my question and the issue is still persist

Comment: What's the name of your bucket? At least its pattern/format

Comment: after i change the bucket name, it surprisingly worked. but this time I did from other laptop.